# Merging large number of files into one

Tags: macos, bash, unix, cat

I have around 30 K files. I want to merge them into one. I used CAT but I am getting this error.

```
cat *.n3 > merged.n3

-bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long
```

How to increase the limit of using the "cat" command? Please help me if there is any iterative method to merge a large number of files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a safe way to do it, without the need for `find`:

```
 printf '%s\0' *.n3 | xargs -0 cat > merged.txt
```

(I've also chosen `merged.txt` as the output file, as @MichaelDautermann soundly advises; rename to `merged.n3` afterward).

Note: The reason this works is:

- `printf` is a bash shell *builtin*, whose command line is not subject to the length limitation of command lines passed to *external* executables.
- `xargs` is smart about partitioning the input arguments (passed via a *pipe* and thus also not subject to the command-line length limit) into multiple invocations so as to avoid the length limit; in other words: `xargs` makes as few calls as possible without running into the limit.
- Using `\0` as the delimiter paired with xargs' `-0` option ensures that all filenames - even those with, e.g., embedded spaces or even newlines - are passed through as-is.

Comment: +1 to you for your answer.  Is there any reason one would choose to use "`printf`" over "`find`", aside from it being a preference? And if we're still using "`*.n3`" as the argument to "`printf`", wouldn't the O.P. still have a problem of "`Argument list too long`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I prefer the `printf` approach for brevity and readability (to only match in the current dir without recursion, your `find` command would get even longer). No, the `"Argument list too long"` problem only affects *external* utilities, whereas `printf` (at least as invoked here) is a bash *builtin*.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way

```
> merged.n3
for file in *.n3
do
  cat "$file" >> merged.n3
done
```

Comment: +1. Slow, but solid; make sure that output file `merged.n3` doesn't already exist - otherwise you'll get into an infinite loop with an ever-growing file.

Answer (score 3):

Try using "`find`":

```
 find . -name \*.n3 -exec cat {} > merged.txt \;
```

This "finds" all the files with the "`n3`" extension in your directory and then passes each result to the "`cat`" command.

And I set the output file name to be "`merged.txt`", which you can rename to "`merged.n3`" after you're done appending, since you likely do not want your new "`merged.n3`" file appending within itself.

Comment: Good point re output filename; if you replace `\;` with `+`, you'll get only a *few* invocations of `cat` (with as many matches as will fit without breaking the length limit), as opposed to one for every matching file; also, your command will find files in the entire *subtree* of the current dir.