# Efficient method to parse large number of files

Tags: shell, parsing, rhel, memory-efficient

I've incoming data which will be in range of 130GBs - 300GBs containing 1000's (maybe millions) of small `.txt` files of size 2KB - 1MB in a SINGLE folder. I want to parse them efficiently.

I'm looking at the following options (Referred from - [21209029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209029/merging-large-number-of-files-into-one)]:

1. Using `printf` + `xargs` (followed by `egrep` & `awk` text processing)

   ```
   printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 cat | egrep -i -v 'pattern1|...|pattern8' | awk '{gsub(/"\t",",")}1' > all_in_1.out
   ```
2. Using `find` + `cat` (followed by `egrep` & `awk` text processing)

   ```
   find . -name \*.txt -exec cat {} > all_in_1.tmp \;
   cat all_in_1.tmp | egrep -i -v 'pattern1|...|pattern8' | awk '{gsub(/"\t",",")}1' > all_in_1.out
   ```
3. Using `for` loop

   ```
   for file in *.txt
   do
     cat "$file" | egrep -i -v 'pattern1|...|pattern8' | awk '{gsub(/"\t",",")}1' >> all_in_1.out
   done
   ```

Which one of the above is the most efficient? Is there a better way to do it?

Or is using shell commands not at all recommended to handle this amount of data processing (I do prefer a shell way for this)?

The server has RHEL 6.5 OS with 32 GB memory with 16 Cores (@2.2GHz).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't test those different methods to determine which will work best for your needs?

Comment: @KenWhite , I'll be testing the approaches to check the most efficient method among these, I just wanted to have an idea if there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1 and 3 expand the list of files on the shell command line.  This will not work with a huge number of files.  Approach 1 and 3 also do not work if the files are distributed across many directories (which is likely with millions of files).

Approach 2 makes a copy of all data, so it is inefficient as well.

You should use `find` and pass the file names directly to `egrep`.  Use the `-h` option to suppress the prefix with the file name:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 \
 | xargs -0 egrep -i -v -h 'pattern1|...|pattern8' \
 | awk '{gsub(/"\t",",")}1' > all_in_1.out
```

`xargs` will automatically launch multiple `egrep` processes in sequence to avoid exceeding the command line limit in a single invocation.

Depending on the file contents, it may also be more efficient to avoid the `egrep` processes altogether, and do the filtering directly in `awk`:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 \
 | xargs -0 awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } ! /pattern1|...|pattern8/ {gsub(/"\t",",")}1' > all_in_1.out
```

`BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }` corresponds to the `-i` option of `egrep`, and the `!` inverts the sense of the matching, just like `-v`.  `IGNORECASE` appears to be a GNU extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited my question to state that all the files will reside in a single folder.

Comment: That seems unlikely, to be honest: With file sizes at most 1 MiB and a total of at least 130 GiB, you are looking at a minimum of 130,000 files in a directory, possibly much more. That will stress the file system *a lot*. However, nothing in my answer changes. The problem of the command line length limit still applies.